# Noun regarding flowers which are blooming

Tags: phrase-requests, poetry

Please have a look at the following poetic lines:

"
Two white roses are your cheeks...

the teardrops of sadness which flowed down them

brought them into bloom instead of withering them"

Is it right to say "brought them into bloom"?

Or is it considerably better (but probably less poetic) to say "made them blooming"?

I relied a bit on this https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bloom to write it this way since it uses the phrase "be in (full) bloom".

Comment: "made them blooming" isn't good English

Comment: a poet has ... poetic license!

Comment: Although it does not refer specifically to blooming, you may want to consider "nurturee" instead.  I think it has a better relationship with "wither"

Comment: Regarding the relation of blooming and withering, I can even change the work "wither"...I just thought that it matches well with the analogy of cheeks with roses...see my edited post above...

Comment: @Poete_Maudit Ah, thanks.  Nurture could still work, but it doesn't seem quite as appropriate.

Comment: Any ideas about the expression "brought them into (full) bloom"?

Comment: The expression "brought them into bloom" works fine. I don't see why you need the "full"; it seems somewhat redundant to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Therefore it seems to be ok and, yes I agree, I won't actually add "full" to it.

Answer (score 1):

In the common parlance, you don't "make" something bloom, you "let" it bloom in its own time. This is generally the way bloom is used poetically, which speaking of young people coming of age.

"Bring to bloom" involves providing the proper nurture to allow a plant to bloom. In the case of the quoted poem, the tears "water" the cheek and allow the paleness of the cheek to "bloom."

If you are literally forcing a plant to bloom, which is technically possible, that would be to "induce blooms."

"Make it bloom" would not usually be heard, as laypersons don't thinking of forcing a flower to bloom. Professionals who might do so would say "induce."

Comment: Thanks for the response, Therefore, "brought them into bloom" sounds good to you as to @Peter Shor. Since I am only living for 1.5 years now in the English-speaking world I do not know yet all these nuances so well. However, my first impression is that even native speakers do not know them so well (I am not talking about you)...haha...

Comment: @tim- But a layperson would likely ask “What makes a flower bloom?” if they were curious.